# VeeValidate 4 validate without submit button

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to wrap my head around VeeValidate 4 but it's quite different from the previous version so I run in to a lot of question marks and obstacles.
I work with a Vue 3 app, using the composition API, with a couple of forms in different components/views. There is a "Next page" button which takes you to the next view, but as that button is lying completely separate from the forms I don't have any handleSubmit connected to the forms. Instead I want to keep it in the state if the current form is valid or not, and that way determine if the user is allowed to go to the next page.

What I would like to accomplish, but am not sure if I can, is to be able to "hook into" when the field validations are happening and that way save to the state if all form fields are valid or not. I've looked through the documentation many times but I can't figure it out. I would greatly appreciate any kind of help, tips or thoughts.

This is a simplified version of one of my Vue components/views:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <CustomInput v-model="name" inputType="text" name="name" />
        <div v-if="nameErrors.length">{{ nameErrors[0] }}</div>

        <CustomInput v-model="width" inputType="text" name="width" />
        <div v-if="widthErrors.length">{{ widthErrors[0] }}</div>
    </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { useField } from 'vee-validate';
import CustomInput from 'CustomInput.vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'View',
    components: {
        CustomInput,
    },
    setup() {
        const { value: name, errors: nameErrors } = useField('name', 'required');
        const { value: width, errors: widthErrors } = useField('width', 'required|numeric|boatWidth');

        return {
            name,
            width,
            nameErrors,
            widthErrors,
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

**Component hiearchy:**

```
LayoutComponent
    FormComponent (which component depends on what step the user is on)
    NextButtonComponent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `useForm` function to gain access to the form state. You can use `inject/provide` for that:

```js
// in parent component
const { meta, errors } = useForm();

provide('form_meta', meta);
provide('form_errors', errors);
```

Then in your child components you can inject these properties:

```js
const formMeta = inject('form_meta');
const formErrors = inject('form_errors');
```

Comment: How does that work with the form not being in the parent? 

I managed to access form state within the child component where my form is (as in my example above). That might work well enough for what I need to do. I can watch meta and keep track of if my form is valid, and save that to my state. That might even work better since my parent component will most likely have different forms in different components.

Comment: I am curious though how to get the childs formstate to the parent with the provide and inject. I tried it and the parent meta didn't update according to the form in the child component. Does the child need to emit, or similar, in order for the parent to have an up to date formstate? If my question makes sense. :)

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure why do you need the form state to go up the tree instead of down. I'm working on some enhancements in a PR but again it's concerned with getting form state down to child components. 

For parent you either could use `emit` or `$refs`.

Comment: My issue is that my Vue app (that consists of different steps) has a layout component that displays different components that have forms in them, but only has one submit/next button. I've edited my original post with the hierarchy.


I was thinking the way to solve this would be to know the form state of the child component in Layout.vue, the parent, and then tell the button to act accordingly. But I may be approaching this in the wrong way.

Comment: you can use `provide/inject` to send data back to the parent which should work better than events. This issue has similar needs 

https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2915